# Assigning Object to Association Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have the following model with their relationships:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :business, :inverse_of => :account
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account, :inverse_of => :business
  has_many :customers, :inverse_of => :business
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business, :inverse_of => :customers
end
```

An `account` owns a `business`, and a `business` has many customers associated with it.

In my controller, after setting a customer instance, I then try to do the following:

```
@customer.business = @account.business
```

When inspecting `@customer.business`, and `@account.business`, all works fine. However, when I try to do: `@account.business.customers`, I always get an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you saved the customer after assigning it the business of the account?

Comment: That was it! Had no clue this mattered. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, they have to be saved at some point to be given ids, which is what will be queried for in the associations.